# Why does plotly incorrectly interpret this ISO datetime string?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, plotly, gantt-chart

The following piece of python code that uses a ISO-formatted date string produces the graph below.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

bars = pd.DataFrame([{'Task': 'kitter_pick', 'Start': '2020-07-22T23:09:18.221013', 'Finish': '2020-07-22T23:09:25.221013', 'Counter': 2465}])

fig = px.timeline(bars, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task",hover_name='Counter')
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")  # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDmeV.png)
The snippet is similar to https://plotly.com/python/time-series/ from the plotly documentation.

The timescale is completely incorrect due to the finish attribute being incorrectly interpreted by plotly.

When changing the timestrings slightly you obtain the correct result:

```
bars = pd.DataFrame([{'Task': 'kitter_pick', 'Start': '2020-07-22T23:09:18.221013', 'Finish': '2020-07-22T23:10:25.221013', 'Counter': 2465}])
```

[correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5q6z.png)

Does anybody know why this happens and if there is a way around this?

I have also tried:

- datetime.datetime objects
- np.datetime64 objects

Both gave the same results

Comment: Wow! i tinkered a little with the time difference, and this problem triggers for me when the two times are less than 10 seconds apart, as soon as the difference is 0.000001s less than 10s in positive or negative, my chart goes crazy. It is 10-exclusive on both sides; that feels like a plotly bug to me

Comment: Yeah I found the same thing. I'll upload a bug report.

Comment: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2658